# cocos2d-x: Box2d Scaling

Tags: box2d, cocos2d-x

I have an object b2body, such as a rectangle, how can I reduce it or increase it? As the object itself and its sprite course.
I create an object like this:

```
bool Horizontal_balka::initWithWorld(b2World *world)
{
    NotCut=false;
    star=false;
    deleteStar=false;
    int32 count = 4;
    string file = "Horizontal_balka.png";
    b2Vec2 vertices[] = {
        b2Vec2(0.0/PTM_RATIO,26.0/PTM_RATIO),
        b2Vec2(0.0/PTM_RATIO,0.0/PTM_RATIO),
        b2Vec2(412.0/PTM_RATIO,0.0/PTM_RATIO),
        b2Vec2(412.0/PTM_RATIO,26.0/PTM_RATIO)
        /*b2Vec2(60.0/PTM_RATIO,14.0/PTM_RATIO),
         b2Vec2(34.0/PTM_RATIO,59.0/PTM_RATIO),
         b2Vec2(28.0/PTM_RATIO,59.0/PTM_RATIO)*/
    };
    CCSize screen = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize();
    b2Body *body = createBodyForWorld(world, b2Vec2(screen.width/2/PTM_RATIO, screen.height/2/PTM_RATIO), 0, vertices, count, 5.0, .2, .2);
        PolygonSprite::initWithFile(file, body, true);

    return true;
}
```

**PolygonSprite.cpp**:

```
bool PolygonSprite::initWithFile(string filename, b2Body *body, bool original)
{
    CCTexture2D *texture = CCTextureCache::sharedTextureCache()->addImage(filename.c_str());
    return initWithTexture(texture, body, original);
}

bool PolygonSprite::initWithTexture(cocos2d::CCTexture2D *texture, b2Body *body, bool original)
{
    b2Fixture *originalFixture = body->GetFixtureList();
    b2PolygonShape *shape = (b2PolygonShape*)originalFixture->GetShape();
    int vertextCount = shape->GetVertexCount();
    vector<Vector2d> points;

    for (int i = 0; i < vertextCount; i++)
    {
        Vector2d p = Vector2d(shape->GetVertex(i).x * PTM_RATIO, shape->GetVertex(i).y * PTM_RATIO);
        points.push_back(p);
    }
    PRFilledPolygon::initWithPointsAndTexture(points, texture);
    _body = body;
    _body->SetUserData(this);
    _original = original;
    _centriod = _body->GetLocalCenter();
    this->setAnchorPoint(ccp(_centriod.x * PTM_RATIO / texture->getContentSize().width,
                             _centriod.y * PTM_RATIO / texture->getContentSize().height));
    return true;
}
```

How can I reduce the size of the object in 2 times? And of course to the sprite itself is diminished

Comment: Are you trying to reduce a specific object relative to other objects or are you trying to reduce the size of all objects in your scene at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

You can't, and you shouldn't. There are a number of problems associated with dynamically growing or shrinking a body's shape which is why it isn't supported in the first place.

You can only do this by removing the body's shape and replace it with another shape that was scaled accordingly. Scaling the corresponding sprite is straightforward.

One problem associated with scaling physics bodies is that when two bodies are in contact, and you scale one of them marginally, it will push the contacting bodies away and not necessarily in a "physically correct" way. If you scale by large amounts in a single frame, you can partially or wholly contain other bodies in the resized body, forcing them outside the body within a single frame, making them "pop out" of the resized body towards the nearest non-contacting position.

That said, if your physics simulation is controlled, has few bodies and rare contacts and you scale the body in small steps using the "replace shape" method it still might work well enough for your requirements.

Comment: How do I create an object with a larger? I added code in the description PolygonSprite

Comment: You have the original vertices used by the shape. Assuming 0,0 is at the center all you need to do is to multiply each point's x/y coordinates by the scale factor. Then remove the existing shape from the body, then create a shape with the new points and add it to the body. Keep doing that every frame if you want to animate the size change.

Comment: I still can not understand how I can increase the sprite before add it to the scene. Help, please))

Comment: the sprite has a scale property

Comment: and that's a subclass of ... hmmm CCNode perhaps? ;)

Comment: is a subclass PRFilledPolygon PRFilledPolygon subclass CCnode. I have a picture loaded into CCTexture2d and I need to be doubled for example. + Vertix I increased 2 times then .... So how CCTexture2d enlarge ...